# Why does Google Chrome listen on port 8000?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, ipv6

Occasionally when starting up a development server (again), it will die with the message that the port 8000 is already in use.

Running

```
$ lsof -n -i4TCP:8000 | grep LISTEN
```

then reveals

```
Google    18638  <user>  450u  IPv6 0x9b020d3ae3f0d7e9      0t0  TCP *:irdmi (LISTEN)
```

The only workaround at the time of writing is to restart Chrome entirely.
Is there an explanation for this opening of a port (a plugin maybe) or is it related to the development server that ran on 0.0.0.0:8000?

Comment: What is the nature of this development server, and what does it have to do with Chrome?

Comment: This is possibly something to do with [Chrome's Remote Debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) capabilities, try going to `chrome://inspect` and see if that gives you any clues.

Comment: I suggest you check if this is actually Google Chrome by checking the process `ps aux | grep 18638`.

Comment: 2018, and it seems that the current version of chrome does not listen on the port (Version 70.0.3538.110 (Official Build) (64-bit) MacOS)

Comment: @line-o u should add the command shared by @fetzig to your answer; `ps aux | grep 18638`; because it  wasnt chrome, in my case it was simply a docker container but it said chrome when I used your command

Answer (score 1):

I believe it has to do with listening for external devices for casting. You could try disabling the flags that contain "media". I haven't been able to narrow down which flag is actually doing the listening. chrome://flags/#hardware-media-key-handling. Try searching for media

Answer (score -1):

If you have a process listening on a port and you kill that process, it will not immediately unbind that port. I think the default on most Linux systems is a 5 minute wait. Check the socket(7) man page and look for SO_REUSEADDR.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question of why Chrome is listening on that port. Please [edit] your post so it's clear how it relates to the question.

Answer (score -1):

That's because 8000 port is used as an alternative http port

[source](https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=8000)

Comment: the link does not provide any information on chrome

Comment: but it says that 8000 is an alternative http port so maybe some extensions are using it. Anyway my chrome doesn't listen on that port.